# Is Android Text to Speech Reliable?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, voice

I'm a fairly new Android developer working on an app that I would like to have speak text that the app supplies.  I have found several examples on using the Text to Speech feature on Android phones, such as [this one](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/search/label/Text-to-Speech))
 and I've been able to get them to work much of the time, but they don't consistently work without problems on the Eclipse Emulator or the HTC phone I use to test.  Problems include the speech working sometimes and sometimes not, or the app causing the phone to go to google play to download "SpeechSynthesis Data Installer" even though the phone has already demonstrated the ability to do text to speech and even though the store says that the item is already installed on the phone.  I won't go into all the examples of issues but there are several more that I have come across in a few hours.

My question is has anyone put the Text to Speech feature in an app put in the marketplace or on multiple phones and found it to be relatively reliable, simple and straightforward, or is it an unreliable and inconsistent feature no matter how well it is implemented?  Thanks.

Comment: I've found it works fairly well, but will occasionally glitch and think it needs to be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks Gabe.  Were you able to try it on more than one phone?

Comment: Yes, I had a few beta testers and even a few purchases (not enough to pay back dev costs, but oh well).  I forget what the breakdown was, but the devices were from multiple OEMs and OS versions.

Comment: Thanks Gabe.  That's encouraging.  Can you point me to any online code that you would say is the most reliable?

Comment: THe one you linked looks ok, although I decided to remove the check for installation-  that seemed to be the buggiest part (although my app did have a preferences screen and that one did check for installation).  I also decided that the default speed was too fast and downed it to 90% speed or so.